# Do I keep the Free Rider Rank after being promoted or fired?

Tags: dont-get-fired

So, basic question. Do I keep the "Free Loader/Rider" Rank after I get promoted or fired?

Answer (score 1):

The Free Rider Position only lasts for the current rank you are at (e.g Free Rider Assistant Manager). Once you go up a rank, it will be gone.